# How to save a MS Chart in WMF format and insert in the PDF iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, mschart, wmf

I've been working in an ASP.NET MVC application (C#) in Visual Studio 2012. I've created several reports with MS Charts (to show them in a pdf file I've used iTextSharp). But, my charts have a very bad quality when they're zoomed on 200%. Because of that I would like to save my charts in WMF format (I found the iTextSharp doesn't support SVG format). To save my chart in WMF format I've used the next code:

```
 using (var chartimage = new MemoryStream())
            {

                chartCentersByYear.SaveImage(chartimage, ChartImageFormat.Png);
                using (var imageSys = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(chartimage))
                {

                    var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageSys, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Wmf);
                    image.ScalePercent(50f);

                    image.SetAbsolutePosition(document.LeftMargin + 40, document.BottomMargin + 95);

                    document.Add(image);
                }

            }
```

but I've received an error in the line:

```
var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageSys, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Wmf);
```

The error is:"Value cannot be null. Parameter name: encoder". How can I save a chart in WMF format? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: _To save my chart in WMF format I've used the next code:_ and _chartCentersByYear.SaveImage(chartimage, ChartImageFormat.Png);_ doen'd look consistent. You can use one of the ChartImageFormat.Emf formats and hope iTextSharp can process it. Or you can upscale the Chart (a lot) before saving a PNG file..

Comment: Thank you, I've tried with `ChartImageFormat.Emf` but it doesn't work. The error is in `var imageSys = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(chartimage)`

Comment: Yes, only very few applicaton understand this or the other emf formats. It would be much more elegant than creating a huge png..

Answer (score 2):

Note: This answer uses iText7 for .NET, not the deprecated iTextSharp

Here is a working example of the functionality in a Console application. This places the mschart as a vector image with perfect quality no matter how much you zoom in.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

    // Create a chart.
    Chart chart1 = new Chart();
    chart1.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
    Series series1 = new Series();
    series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 2));
    series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 4));
    series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 1));
    chart1.Series.Add(series1);

    // Save the chart to an in-memory (emf) metafile.
    Metafile metafile;
    using (MemoryStream str1 = new MemoryStream()) {
        chart1.SaveImage(str1, ChartImageFormat.Emf);

        byte[] emfBytes = str1.ToArray();
        IntPtr hemf = SetEnhMetaFileBits((uint) emfBytes.Length, emfBytes);
        metafile = new Metafile(hemf, true);
    }

    // Convert the metafile to a WMF and write to a file.
    byte[] wmfBytes = GetWmfByteArray(metafile);
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\temp\test.wmf", wmfBytes);

    // Initialize the document.
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(@"c:\temp\test.pdf");
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdf);

    // Add the image.
    PdfFormXObject xObject1 = new PdfFormXObject(new WmfImageData(@"c:\temp\test.wmf"), pdf);
    Image img1 = new Image(xObject1);
    document.Add(img1);

    document.Close();
}

[DllImport("gdiplus.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GdipEmfToWmfBits(int hEmf, int uBufferSize, byte[] bBuffer, int iMappingMode, EmfToWmfBitsFlags flags);
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetEnhMetaFileBits(uint cbBuffer, byte[] lpBuffer);

[Flags]
private enum EmfToWmfBitsFlags
{
    EmfToWmfBitsFlagsDefault = 0x00000000,
    EmfToWmfBitsFlagsEmbedEmf = 0x00000001,
    EmfToWmfBitsFlagsIncludePlaceable = 0x00000002,
    EmfToWmfBitsFlagsNoXORClip = 0x00000004
}

private static byte[] GetWmfByteArray(Metafile mf) {
    const int MM_ANISOTROPIC = 8;
    int handle = mf.GetHenhmetafile().ToInt32();
    int bufferSize = GdipEmfToWmfBits(handle, 0, null, MM_ANISOTROPIC, EmfToWmfBitsFlags.EmfToWmfBitsFlagsIncludePlaceable);
    byte[] buf = new byte[bufferSize];
    GdipEmfToWmfBits(handle, bufferSize, buf, MM_ANISOTROPIC, EmfToWmfBitsFlags.EmfToWmfBitsFlagsIncludePlaceable);
    return buf;
}
```

Here's another snippet that works with the older iTextSharp:

```
// Create a chart.
Chart chart1 = new Chart();
chart1.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
Series series1 = new Series();
series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 2));
series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 4));
series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 1));
chart1.Series.Add(series1);

// Save to metafile.
chart1.SaveImage(@"c:\temp\test.emf", ChartImageFormat.Emf);

// Convert to WMF.
Metafile mf = new Metafile(@"c:\temp\test.emf");
byte[] arr = GetWmfByteArray(mf);
ImgWMF wmf = new ImgWMF(arr);
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(wmf);

// Create PDF.
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(@"c:\temp\test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
document.Open();
document.Add(img);
document.Close();
```

<s>Note that there is currently no way (that I know of) to place a in-memory WMF in an iText PDF without loading it from a file, because of a bug. I made a [pull request](https://github.com/itext/itext7/pull/41) with a fix, so hopefully they merge it sometime soon.</s>

Update! Pull request has been merged and this issue is fixed in [iText 7.1.8](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/releases/release-itext-718): You can now do `new WmfImageData(wmfBytes)`, taking away the need to write to a file.

Update (april 2020): Unfortunately a recent Windows Update (KB4549951) seems to have broken the GdipEmfToWmfBits function (which is used to convert from EMF to WMF). Aside from uninstalling the update I do not yet know of a permanent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately with this update, the GdipEmfToWmfBits function stopped working properly with the EmfToWmfBitsFlagsIncludePlaceable flag, which is a byte structure with PDF resolution information that is mandatory for iText or iTextSharp. I tried an alternative that was to create this header on the nail. And to my surprise, it worked. Here is a snippet of code I'm using.

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct PLACEABLEMETAHEADER
    {
        public uint Key; // Magic number (always 9AC6CDD7h)
        public ushort Handle; // Metafile HANDLE number (always 0) /
        public short Left; // Left coordinate in metafile units /
        public short Top; // Top coordinate in metafile units /
        public short Right; // Right coordinate in metafile units /
        public short Bottom; // Bottom coordinate in metafile units /
        public ushort Inch; // Number of metafile units per inch /
        public uint Reserved; // Reserved (always 0) /
        public ushort Checksum; // Checksum value for previous 10 WORDs */
    }

    private byte[] GetMetafileRawData(Metafile metafile)
    {
        byte[] data = null;

        System.Drawing.Imaging.MetafileHeader header = metafile.GetMetafileHeader();

        const int MM_ANISOTROPIC = 8;

        IntPtr handle = metafile.GetHenhmetafile();

        try
        {
            EmfToWmfBitsFlags flag = EmfToWmfBitsFlags.EmfToWmfBitsFlagsIncludePlaceable;

            uint dataSize = GdipEmfToWmfBits(handle, 0, null, MM_ANISOTROPIC, flag);

            if (dataSize == 0) //Not Support EmfToWmfBitsFlagsIncludePlaceable
            {
                flag = EmfToWmfBitsFlags.EmfToWmfBitsFlagsDefault;

                dataSize = GdipEmfToWmfBits(handle, 0, null, MM_ANISOTROPIC, flag);
            }

            data = new byte[dataSize];

            GdipEmfToWmfBits(handle, dataSize, data, MM_ANISOTROPIC, flag);

            if (flag == EmfToWmfBitsFlags.EmfToWmfBitsFlagsDefault) //Add PlaceableMetaHeader to Byte Array
            {
                List<byte> placeableList = new List<byte>();

                PLACEABLEMETAHEADER placeable = new PLACEABLEMETAHEADER();

                placeable.Key = 0x9AC6CDD7; //Fix
                placeable.Left = (short) header.Bounds.Left;
                placeable.Top = (short) header.Bounds.Top;
                placeable.Right = (short) header.Bounds.Width;
                placeable.Bottom = (short) header.Bounds.Height;
                placeable.Inch = 1440; //Fix?!?!?!?!

                placeable.Checksum = 0;
                placeable.Checksum ^= (ushort) (placeable.Key & 0x0000FFFF);
                placeable.Checksum ^= (ushort) ((placeable.Key & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
                placeable.Checksum ^= (ushort) placeable.Handle;
                placeable.Checksum ^= (ushort) placeable.Left;
                placeable.Checksum ^= (ushort) placeable.Top;
                placeable.Checksum ^= (ushort) placeable.Right;
                placeable.Checksum ^= (ushort) placeable.Bottom;
                placeable.Checksum ^= (ushort) placeable.Inch;
                placeable.Checksum ^= (ushort) (placeable.Reserved & 0x0000FFFF);
                placeable.Checksum ^= (ushort) ((placeable.Reserved & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);

                placeableList.AddRange(this.SerializeSequentialStruct(placeable));
                placeableList.AddRange(data);

                data = placeableList.ToArray();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            DeleteEnhMetaFile(handle);
        }

        return data;
    }

    private byte[] SerializeSequentialStruct(object @struct)
    {
        byte[] arr = null;

        IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;

        try
        {
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(@struct) - 2;
            arr = new byte[size];
            ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(@struct, ptr, true);
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }

        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks @Isaque. I noticed I could ignore the checksum and leave it at just `placeable.Checksum = 0;`, and it still works.